# Check if one and/or the other table contains a specific value in same query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm attempting to check if either of my two `tables` contains a specific value in the `content_key` column. One table is for public content (`content`), and the other is for submissions (`content_submissions`). When a user submits content (YouTube video id's, etc) to us, I want to check if it has already been submitted to us, whether it be in the public table or the private (submissions) table. This way we don't end up having accepting duplicates of the same content during the submission process.

The two tables would look like this.

`content`

```
*----*-------------*
| id | content_key |
*----*-------------*    
| 1  | sOWewQO3hpg |
*----*-------------*
| 2  | e2CJgQjH5lE |
*----*-------------*
```

`content_submissions`

```
*----*-------------*
| id | content_key |
*----*-------------*    
| 1  | BOtcpPVNvhA |
*----*-------------*
```

So when the user submits the key `e2CJgQjH5lE` or `BOtcpPVNvhA` (at different times), I want the query to tell me that the key is already in the database.

The reason I don't simply have an `active` column in the `content` table instead of having two table is because it will significantly increase the id each time content is not accepted, making the urls a bit random, and not sequential.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can combined the rows of both table using `UNION`

```
SELECT COUNT(content_key)
FROM
    (
        SELECT content_key
        FROM content
        UNION
        SELECT content_key
        FROM content_submissions
    ) a
WHERE content_key = 'valHere'
```

It will simply return `0` if the value your are looking for doesn't exists otherwise the total number of records that matches will be shown.

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73367/8)

Hope this helps.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
    (Select content_key from content union select content_key from content_submissions) v
WHERE content_key = 'new key'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id from content
where content.content_key="myKey"
UNION
select id from content_submissions
content_submissions.content_key="myKey"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use

```
SELECT *
FROM content
WHERE content_key = value
UNION
SELECT *
FROM content_submissions
WHERE content_key = value
```

that should do it.

From [13.2.8.4. UNION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

> UNION is used to combine the result from multiple SELECT statements
> into a single result set.
>
> The default behavior for UNION is that duplicate rows are removed from
> the result.